# Doctrine query postgres json (contains) json_array

Tags: json, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

The `json_array` type of doctrine is saved to a [postgres database > 9.2 as json datatype](http://doctrine-dbal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/types.html#mapping-matrix).

Postgres [supports contains and lots of other operations](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html) on the json datatype. Is there any possibility to use the functionalities in doctrine?

Probably a custom SQLWalker is needed for that? As described [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#adding-your-own-functions-to-the-dql-language). Also a custom type supporting `JSONB` would be nice. As described [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/custom-mapping-types.html). This would increase the performance when querying for the json field. Or is there a custom lib that adds the `json(b)` functionality or is it even possibile using `DQL`.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing, i found this while searching: https://github.com/opsway/doctrine-dbal-postgresql though it's still missing some operators. 
About jsonb I can tell you they are implementing the jsonb data type through an option but it's not available yet https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/824

Comment: @valepu I created a Symfony Bundle to support jsonb. https://github.com/boldtrn/JsonbBundle it works well

Comment: nice to hear, i might be using this sooner or later

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I created a Symfony2 Bundle that supports jsonb.

Hope this helps.

https://github.com/boldtrn/JsonbBundle

Right now I prefer to use NativQueries instead of custom DQL functions to query for my jsonb fields. The custom functions are too cumbersome in my application.

Everything should be documented in the Bundle as well.

Comment: Very nice, Thanks for the bundle.

Comment: Many thanks for creating this bundle, was going crazy for last 2 days.